# How to remove a specific class in web page?

Tags: javascript

My javascript script doesn't work.

I would like in my web page have a javascript function to remove all class attribute contain 'plane'

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="test toto plane">
<a href="#" class="test toto">
<span class="plane car">
```

My goal is to have

```
<a href="#" class="test toto ">
<a href="#" class="test toto">
<span class="car">
```

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("plane"), function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        item.classList.remove('plane');
    });
})();
```

querySelectorAll find nothing element.

Comment: plane is a class, so you have to add a dot to your querySelector `document.querySelectorAll(".plane")`

Comment: The callback to forEach on an empty array will never get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter for the `querySelectorAll()` method must be a [valid CSS selector string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Parameters).

Change `document.querySelectorAll("plane")` to `document.querySelectorAll(".plane")`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the "dot" for looking up an element by class.

Simply use:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.querySelectorAll('.plane').forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
        item.classList.remove('plane');
    });
})();
```